# Single or Multiple Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community

We have multi salesforce instance structure in the organisation. We have recently implemented SF Community C1 with Org 1 (BU1), now BU 2 also wants to have SF Community implemented with Org 2 as C2.

The customers are the same in C1 and Org2, so the question is should create a new community with Org1 or should we create a new community c2 in Org 2 that also has the customer data.

Please would be great if you can provide your answers with advantages and disadvantages of the approach.

We can use Lightning out/ETL/ API to levearge data from Org 2 for visualisation purposes.

Comment: This question might be too much opinion based for this site as it is not a specific programming question. What are the communities being used for - case management, customer contact as this could change the answer?